# Change behavior of "control" and "shift" keys in OrbitControls

Tags: three.js, orbitcontrols

Using a scene with `OrbitControls` and as far as I can tell by default pressing the `ctrl` and `shift` key reverts the left and right mouse movements.
in my setup left mouse click rotatoes arounds the scene and right mouse clicks move around the 2d plain.
how can I disable the `ctrl` and `shift` key reversing that?

a hack I found is to edit the controls `mouseButtons` back when the keys are pressed:

```
 this.controls.mouseButtons = {
      LEFT: shouldSwitch ? 2 : 0,
      MIDDLE: 1,
      RIGHT: shouldSwitch ? 0 : 2,
    };
```

using `r141`

Answer (score 2):

`OrbitControls` does not allow disable the processing of "control", "shift" and "meta" keys. You would need a custom modification and remove the following two sections:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/f30599ed21818efbbffee6e923957616fd410016/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js#L905-L913

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/f30599ed21818efbbffee6e923957616fd410016/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js#L927-L935

Changing the mouse button configuration (`OrbitControls.mouseButtons`) when one of the keys are pressed like suggested is also a valid solution.